# (Oracle)Skip scanning table conditionally(SKIP CTE conditionally)

Tags: oracle, common-table-expression

My goal is to THEDATE and VAL in table HISTORY only when
MYREF is NULL.
Below is my code. How to modify in order to skip scanning HISTORY and return the result of MYREF_VAL, when the result of MYREF_VAL temporary table have row?
Because, actual data in HISOTY are massive and I want to sure that the scanning the HISTROY will never occur if MYREF has value.

```
CREATE TABLE HISTORY (THEDATE VARCHAR(20),VAL NUMBER);
INSERT INTO HISTORY VALUES('20170101', 3);
INSERT INTO HISTORY VALUES('20200923', 4);
CREATE TABLE MYREF (THEDATE VARCHAR(20), VAL NUMBER);
INSERT INTO MYREF VALUES( NULL, NULL);


WITH MYREF_VAL AS( SELECT THEDATE, VAL VAL FROM MYREF)
,HISTORY_VAL AS (SELECT THEDATE, VAL FROM HISTORY)
SELECT * FROM HISTORY_VAL  
--Works but, How to modify in order to skip scanning HISTORY and return the result of MYREF_VAL, when the result of MYREF_VAL temporary table have not null?
--such as
--if MYREF has all NULL row, then SELECT * FROM HISTORY 
--if MYREF has any not NULL, then SELECT * FROM MYREF
```

Comment: I don't understand the goal.  The query you posted returns every row from `history` regardless of what is in `myref`.  There is no point in reading `myref` in this query.  If you want to avoid reading the `history` table, what do you actually want the query to return and why?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle can use a FILTER operation to dynamically read from a table based on data from another table. If you create predicates using `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`, Oracle will likely be able to figure it out. The FILTER operation is not thoroughly documented, and I can't tell you exactly when it works, so you'll want to check the explain plan to ensure it's working correct.

For example, add some predicates and generate an explain plan for this query:

```
explain plan for
WITH MYREF_VAL AS( SELECT THEDATE, VAL VAL FROM MYREF)
    ,HISTORY_VAL AS (SELECT THEDATE, VAL FROM HISTORY)
SELECT * FROM MYREF_VAL WHERE THEDATE IS NOT NULL AND VAL IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM HISTORY_VAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MYREF_VAL WHERE THEDATE IS NOT NULL OR VAL IS NOT NULL);
```

Retrieve the explain plan, and notice how the `NOT EXISTS` condition is connected to the FILTER operation for Id=3:

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);


Plan hash value: 4052518700
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |         |     3 |    98 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UNION-ALL          |         |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | MYREF   |     1 |    25 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   FILTER            |         |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| HISTORY |     2 |    24 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| MYREF   |     1 |    25 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - filter("THEDATE" IS NOT NULL AND "VAL" IS NOT NULL)
   3 - filter( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "MYREF" "MYREF" WHERE 
              "THEDATE" IS NOT NULL OR "VAL" IS NOT NULL))
   5 - filter("THEDATE" IS NOT NULL OR "VAL" IS NOT NULL)
```